# Is there a way to visualize or debug hitSlop for a React Native component?

Tags: react-native

I've got a button in my app that feels very hard to tap. I'm pretty sure the tap-target is far too small, and I'd like to improve that - `hitSlop` should do the trick, but for whatever reason, it doesn't seem to have an effect!

I see a note in the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html#hitslop):

> The touch area never extends past the parent view bounds and the
> Z-index of sibling views always takes precedence if a touch hits two
> overlapping views.

...but I feel pretty confident that this note doesn't apply to my situation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

You can find touch area from debugger menu. Follow this step for get your element's touch area,

1. Open debugger menu (for iOS (Cmd + d) & for android (Cmd + m)). Select "Show Inspect" from menu.

   https://i.stack.imgur.com/70LsI.png
2. On press inspect you will get your element's area

   https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTQ06.png
3. Select Touchable from bottom menu, you will get touchable area of your element's area. (Touchable area shown as dotted line)

   https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw9ah.png